# AWK Unexpected Character

Tags: awk

I got the solution for my problem from a fellow. Here is the code.

```
last | awk '{
if(NF>7){
if($(NF-5)=="Mar"){ # You may change the month or even accept it as a parameter
if($(NF-4) != date){datecount++};
match($(NF-3),/^([0-9]+)/,arr);
if(arr[1]>=8 && arr[1]<=16){
# Note I am using different time interval, change it accordingly
count++;
}
}
date=$(NF-4);
}
}
END{
datecount++;
print "Total logins   : ",count;
print "Total dates    : ",datecount;
print "Average logins : ",count/datecount;
}'
```

I tried saving it as name.sh and run it with bash name.sh, i tried to save it name.awk and run it as awk -f name.awk, but i still get the same error:

```
awk: 1: unexpected character '.'
```

I'm not entirely sure i run the script as i should.

NOTE: I'm working on a virtual machine on ubuntu 18.04 (I think) and I'm trying to run the script through terminal.

Comment: Remove parts of your code and see if the error persists, until you have the minimal code which produces this error.  If you still cannot understand what is going on, post  it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have big `}` and `{` braces closing issues :)  Always try to indent your code in nice way so that you will get to know easily where is starting and ending block for your conditions. Could you please try following.

```
last | awk '{
  if(NF>7){
    if($(NF-5)=="Mar"){                
      if($(NF-4) != date){datecount++};
      match($(NF-3),/^([0-9]+)/,arr);
        if(arr[1]>=8 && arr[1]<=16){
          count++;
        }
      date=$(NF-4);
    }
  }
}
END{
datecount++;
print "Total logins   : ",count;
print "Total dates    : ",datecount;
print "Average logins : ",count/datecount;
}'
```

Comment: Yes, it finally gave the expected result. I tried to indent the code as well as i could, but i didn't notice the missing braces. Thanks a mili! You saved my day.

Comment: @SebiCN you can use some editor with braces pairing feature to avoid those problems.